# Running vmlinux ELF under QEMU

Tags: firmware, arm, qemu

I have a vmlinux ELF file to run under QEMU.

My arguments to `qemu-system-arm.exe` are:

- The correct `-cpu` argument.
- The **versatilepb** `-machine` which I'm not sure if it's the right choose, but can't see the other options with `-cpu help`.
- The `-kernel` flag to pass the `vmlinux` file.
- The `-serial stdio -nographic` flags with `"console=ttyAMA0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0"` kernel arguments.

Why I don't see any output? I also tried the `-D` flag to get a log file.